# How to read node js log messages remotely

Tags: node.js, server

My NodeJS/Express server files are hosted by AWS. I want to read the log messages and tried connecting to my remote server like this:

```
ssh -i "server.pem" ec2-user@ipaddress.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

And then I entered my backend directory where all my server files are and ran the following command:

```
node server.js
```

I get the message in my terminal:

```
We have started our server on port 9000
```

My question: Where do I view this server to read all the log messages? When I go to localhost:9000 the page says site not found. And when I go to the remote site jarvis.magainteractive.com, nothing changes in my terminal. I want to be able to see all the console messages from my '/message' and my '/' routes in my terminal.

Below is my server.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

require('./routes/main')(app);

var server = app.listen(9000,function(){
    console.log("We have started our server on port 9000");
});
```

Below is my routes file (main.js):

```
module.exports = function(app) {

app.post('/message', function (request, response) {
  console.log(request.body); 
  console.log(request.body.Body);
  console.log(request.body.From);

  response.send("<Response><Message>Heyyo!</Message></Response>");
});

app.get('/', function(req,res) {    
    console.log("Welcome to home"); 
    res.render('index', {title:"Home page", description:"Welcome to the Jarvis HD Backend"});
});

}
```

Comment: have you configured nginx to serve your node app ? If not you will need to do that first.

Comment: @kailashyogeshwar I have not. How do I do that?

Comment: you will need to install the nginx on server i will share a doc with steps ignore last part. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1d8emkkb0oXLnL6gxkII0xOKQwKrr72z0A_CrmtAVjwQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to see the app logs like console.logs in realtime at your terminal i would suggest starting your app using"

```
pm2 start app.js -n jarvis.com
```

and then to view all the app logs you can use :

```
pm2 logs [app_id]
```

you can see which app are running using :

```
pm2 list
```

Comment: Do I run this in the terminal after `ssh -i "server.pem" ec2-user@ipaddress.compute-1.amazonaws.com ` Also, where can I get the app_id?

Comment: yes in shell but before that you need to install "npm install -g pm2" to see the app id execute pm2 list it will show list of apps with id's.

Answer (score 1):

First, when you run `node server.js` in your SSH shell, the node process you created will only live as long as you keep the SSH connection open.

The `console.log` messages you're looking for will show up in your SSH window when they happen. The message `We have started our server on port 9000` is coming from the 2nd to last line in `server.js`.

`http://localhost:9000` didn't work either because you tried it on your own computer (localhost points to 127.0.0.1 which is your own computer) or you exited the Node process in your SSH shell and did something like `wget http://localhost:9000` (which failed because you exited the Node process so your server stopped).

`jarvis.magainteractive.com` didn't work because your node server was running on port 9000. When you connect to `http://jarvis.magainteractive.com` you are connecting over port 80 to your server.

---

Like one of the comments said, you can install Nginx. It will let you proxy port 80 requests to the server's local port 9000. You don't have to use Nginx but it's very easy to configure and get setup. Then you can connect to `http://jarvis.magainteractive.com` and it will make a request to port 9000.

As for Node exiting whenever you stop the node process or exit SSH you have a bunch of options. Personally, I use `pm2` because it will restart the node process for you whenever it crashes. `forever` is another popular option. You can also use the basic `nohup` command to put the Node process into the background so it keeps running after you exit SSH session - it's just more of a pain to stop/restart the server.

Comment: If I can't view my backend log messages in localhost or my live url, where is my port running then (9000)? SSH is somehow reading my first console message "We have started our server on port 9000" so my server should be running somewhere for me to be able to visit other routes that I have setup like the index. Basically what steps do I need to follow to be able to see the console message "Welcome to home" that is setup in my index route? Is nginx the only way?

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing several things up. The log messages you're looking for have nothing to do what HTTP or the port. When you call `node server.js`, you are simply starting a process which executes your javascript. When you `console.log('message')`, it simply writes that text to the process's `stdout` (which is just displayed in your console window and nowhere else). When you make an HTTP request to your server, Express (`app.get('/'...`) receives the message and you respond by calling `res.render(...`. That renders your template and sends it back to your browser.

Comment: When I started my server locally on my computer and would view the server files on my localhost, I was able to see all my console messages in my terminal as I visited different routes. Is there a way to do that remotely? My main issue is I want to see if my POST route is working.